# Obtaining serializer for a class in kotlinx.serialization

Tags: kotlin, serialization, reflection, kotlinx.serialization

Assume that `C` is a serializable class:

```kotlin
@Serializable
class C
```

I have at least four ways of obtaining serializer for this class.

1. Companion(?) function. Actually IDEA doesn't let me to go to declaration, so I assume it's a kind of synthetic compiler-plugn-generated function.

```kotlin
val s = C.serializer()
```

2. `serializer()` call with reified type argument:

```kotlin
val s = serializer<C>()
```

3. KClass experimental extension:

```kotlin
val c = C()
val s1 = C::class.serializer()
val s2 = c::class.serializer()
```

4. `serializer()` semi-experimental overload:

```kotlin
val c = C()
val s1 = serializer(C::class.createType())
val s2 = serializer(c::class.createType())
```

The last two ways seem to be more powerful: for example, I may use it for polymorphic serialization getting actual KClass for an instance of abstract type and choosing the correct serializer.

I have several questions:

1. What ways of obtaining serializer by type actually exist and what ways are preferrable?
2. As I understand, I may register several serializers for one class, so which one do I get in each of these cases?
3. Assuming I've registered a custom serializer for a class using `@Serializable(with=...)`, is it possible to obtain a standard serializer for it somehow?

Comment: The official guide covers both supported means https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#introduction-to-serializers (the choice between them is mostly stylistic) while the docs for the corresponding experimental functions list their limitations https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-core/kotlinx-serialization-core/kotlinx.serialization/serializer.html

Answer (score 1):

```
val c = C()
val s1 = serializer(C::class.javaObjectType)
```

satisfy me